# I'm losing binary data when using fseek in c

Tags: c, hex, fwrite, fseek, hex-editors

I wrote a function that is responsible for moving to a binary file and editing its bytes

```
int replace(FILE *binaryFile, long offset, unsigned char *replaced, int length) {
    if (binaryFile != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            fseek(binaryFile, offset + i, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&replaced[i], sizeof(*replaced), 1, binaryFile);
        }
        fclose(binaryFile);
        return 0;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

When I use this function, I encounter a strange problem
All data in the file is filled with NULL bytes
And only one of the addresses in the file changes

Example:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("target.bin", "wb");

replace(fp, 0x57d8b0, "\x1E\xFF\x2F\xE1", 4);
replace(fp, 0x57c770, "\x01\x00\xA0\xE3\x1E\xFF\x2F\xE1", 8);
```

Result:

```
0x57c770: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
...
0x57d8a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x57d8b0: 1e ff 2f e1
```

Correct result:

```
0x57c770: 01 00 A0 E3 1E FF 2F E1 ...
...
0x57d8a0: 9c c4 0a ea 70 d2 68 00 44 d4 68 00 10 d1 68 00
0x57d8b0: 1e ff 2f e1 18 b0 8d e2 02 8b 2d ed 18 d0 4d e2
```

Please help me to solve the function problem or other problems.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you call `fclose` at the end of the `replace` function, and then call the `replace` function again with the same file pointer? Always check the result of seek and write operations.

Comment: @rmn You can replace the contents of a file if the replacement is the same size. What are you talking about?

Comment: @rmn I thought about this solution, but it slows the program down a lot, so I put it last

Comment: I saw replacing bytes in cpp in an example, now I want to do it in c

Comment: @rmn Not true. You can't *insert* into a file (without copying the *remainder* of the file), but you definitely *replace* bytes of a file.

Comment: @ikegami I fixed fclose but r+b doesn't help and still problem

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, you're right. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wb` is not correct. It clobbers the file.

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen),

| Mode | Meaning | Explanation | If already exists | If does not exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "r" | read | Open a file for reading | read from start | failure to open |
| "w" | write | Create a file for writing | destroy contents | create new |
| "a" | append | Append to a file | write to end | create new |
| "r+" | read extended | Open a file for read/write | read from start | error |
| "w+" | write extended | Create a file for read/write | destroy contents | create new |
| "a+" | append extended | Open a file for read/write | write to end | create new |

You want `r+b`.

---

Also, you close the file handle in `replace`, which is premature. This should be done outside of `replace`, after you're done with the handle.

---

As an aside, you shouldn't be doing a number of seeks and writes of length one equal to `length`; you should be doing one seek and one write of length `length`.

Comment: There is more wrong with OP's code. They close the file handle within the `replace` function. This makes it that it's only possible to do *one* replacement. The second replacement will fail because the file handle was closed.